# Loading text with animation

Tags: android, textview, loading

I want to display a buffering text like Buffering..

And I need the dots to NOT be static i.e. every 2 seconds change the number of dots so it goes 'one dot, two dots, 3 dots, one dot and so on.
I was wondering what is the best way to do this. Should the dots be in an image view? Should I have three images each with a specific number of dots? Or is there a different way to animate this?

I have similar thing using handler long back. But in that case i know the end time.

Below is my previous code also:

```
/**
     *  Use to show Loading... text while splash screen is loading. Here after each 350 milliseconds, i am adding 
     *  a single dot(.) using thread and showing in the text view. And after reaching 3 dots, procedure is iterating itself again. 
     *  This code will run till 3500 milliseconds. 
     */
    for (int i = 350; i <= SPLASHTIME; i = i + 350) {
        final int j = i;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (j / 350 == 1 || j / 350 == 4 || j / 350 == 7
                        || j / 350 == 10) {
                    tvLoadingdots.setText(".");
                } else if (j / 350 == 2 || j / 350 == 5 || j / 350 == 8) {
                    tvLoadingdots.setText("..");
                } else if (j / 350 == 3 || j / 350 == 6 || j / 350 == 9) {
                    tvLoadingdots.setText("...");
                }
            }
        }, i);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me the best way for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

I used a Text Switcher and a runnable to solve this problem

```
private void setupTextSwitcher() {
    mLoadingChatBotTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.chat_bot_loading_text_switcher);
    mLoadingChatBotTextSwitcher.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
    mLoadingChatBotTextSwitcher.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    mLoadingChatBotTextSwitcher.addView(getTextSwitcherTextView());
    mLoadingChatBotTextSwitcher.addView(getTextSwitcherTextView());
}

private TextView getTextSwitcherTextView() {
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.birthday_white, null));
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);
    return textView;
}

private void kickOffLoadingTextAnimation() {
    if(mTextSwitchingHandler == null) {
        mTextSwitchingHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        mTextSwitchingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            int loadingIndex = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch(loadingIndex % 5) {
                    case 0:
                        changeLoadingMessage("Loading.    ");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        changeLoadingMessage("Loading..   ");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        changeLoadingMessage("Loading...  ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        changeLoadingMessage("Loading.... ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        changeLoadingMessage("Loading.....");
                        break;
                }
                loadingIndex++;
                mTextSwitchingHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        };
        mTextSwitchingHandler.post(mTextSwitchingRunnable);
    }
}
```